# Can someone give some basic info on traffic of SO sites?

Tags: support, statistics

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Stack Overflow stats graphs](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65/stack-overflow-stats-graphs)
>   [How many SO users use the site per day?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45169/how-many-so-users-use-the-site-per-day)

If it is suitable, can someone give some info about SO sites' traffic? I would be especially interested in:

- ## of visitors per day of the week (to see on which days more users are loging

  in)
- ## of visitors per hour of the day (to see which hour intervals are preferred more by visitors)
- ## of questions per day of the week & per hour of the day
- ## of answers per day of the week & per hour of the day
- ## of views (of questions) per day of the week & per hour of the day

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't get excited about the duplicate comment upvoter working; I upvoted the comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basic traffic information is available at [QuantCast](http://quantcast.com).

Answer (score 1):

https://www.quantcast.com/stackoverflow.com

[image]