# How many SO users use the site per day?

Tags: discussion, users, statistics

There are roughly 4400 pages of users registered on the SO site.  What is the rough average number of users that use the site per day?

**Edit**

Decided just to do the quick math for Total users (all numbers approximations).
35 users per page
4400 pages
1.5 million registered users, give or take.

Answer (score 6):

https://www.quantcast.com/stackoverflow.com

[image]

Comment: @Chester: awesome!

Comment: WOW!  That's really impressive.  Both the graphics and the numbers.