# Fascinating/enticing facts about Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

Apart from the obvious bits of information like the technology used, the history, reputation system, famous users etc. that are readily available on this site, Jeff's or Joel's blogs, presentations etc., what are some interesting facts or sources of information on Stack Overflow?

While I'm asking this as a general question, my main motive is to come up with an interesting introduction to Stack Overflow in a presentation that I'm going to give in our company. My aim is to 1) get Stack Overflow known to my audience 2) to entice fellow developers to engage in this community.

Some examples: The recent $6 million venture, the fact that Alan Kay is a user, the whole thing about Jon Skeet etc...

Comment: Alan Kay only visited for about a month. Bjarne Stroustrup was only on for a couple of days. If you use C#, though, Eric Lippert might be a big selling point.

Comment: See also: [Hidden features of Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8211/hidden-features-of-stack-overflow)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<strike>I don't have the link handy and I'm too lazy to look it up right now, but</strike> [Greg Hewgill put some graphs together](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65/stack-overflow-stats-graphs) based on the data dump that show stats like the average time to when the accepted answer is posted (hint: it doesn't take very long).

It might also be worth highlighting the data dump itself, and since these are new users a discussion of what questions do *not* belong on Stack Overflow is appreciated.

Comment: <del>I will look for it and find it!</del> Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

The original prototype for SO weighed sixteen tons, required a team of over 100 to man the boilers, and employed armed Pinkerton agents to "close" off-topic questions. New users were frequently maimed by molten lead when the type-setting portion broke during heated "edit wars". On Fridays, idle users would re-use castings to cook waffles, resulting in wide-spread poisoning, madness, and mental retardation... No one noticed anything amiss.

Comment: Clearly this should be the lead answer.