# Provide statistics per tag: mean time for receiving an answer, mean time for upvoting an answer, mean time for accepting an answer

Tags: feature-request, tags

Hi,

I think that the following "per-tag" information would be useful for people, deciding in which of several related or seeming similar tags to ask a question:

1. Mean time for receiving the first answer for a question.
2. Mean time for the first upvote to a question
3. Mean time for accepting an answer.

Imagine you have a pressing question and need a correct answer asap. There are two or three tags that sound similar and most-related to the question. Having the 1, 2, and 3 statistics above, you see that the mean times are lowest for one of the tag (the other two are not so well visited by the experts), and you chose this tag, based on the useful statistics.

Were not the statistics, you may not have chosen this tag, because you didn't think it really belonged there.
This may also change your understanding about the question and into what area it falls most.

Comment: Maybe if you ask Greg really nicely he could grab some of this data: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65/stack-overflow-stats-graphs

Comment: @Jon-Seigel: Greg has something similar to 1. and 3., but I am asking just for the mean, not for a histogram. He hasn't anything similar to 2. Also, I am asking to make this a regular feature of SO -- for example show this when one clicks on the now functioning "statistics" link for a given tag,

Comment: Okay, fair enough. You may want to edit your question to say why these statistics would be useful and how they would be used in the normal flow of asking a question.

Comment: If there are 2+ tags that are so similar to the point where choosing either will not change the meaning of the tag but only how many people view it, then a retag is in order. If they are not that similar, then the most appropriate tag should be chosen.